# Service deactivation when USB connected

Tags: android, android-service

I have doubt whether it is possible to stop service , when USB is connected to PC?

```
if(intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_UMS_DISCONNECTED)) {
     Intent intent2=new Intent(context,MyService.class);
     context.startActivity(intent2);
}
else if (intent.getAction().equals( Intent.ACTION_UMS_CONNECTED)) {
     stopService(new Intent(this, MyService.class));
}
```

I have given this, but it didn't work.

Comment: `did not work` is a good explanation. In which context to you have this code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try another broadcast recever;

```
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    String action = intent.getAction();
    // UsbManager.ACTION_USB_STATE -> "android.hardware.usb.action.USB_STATE" actually
    if (action.equals(UsbManager.ACTION_USB_STATE)) {
        Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
        // UsbManager.USB_CONNECTED -> "connected" actually
        usbConnected = extras.getBoolean(UsbManager.USB_CONNECTED);
        ...
```

Hope this helps.